# urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fedc69d9c50>: Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: python, django

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection error happens.
When I access get_data method,the error happens.
I wrote in get_data method like

```
def get_data(request, **user_id):
        user = UserInfoUtil.user(id, user_id['user_id'])
        print(111)
        uid = user.to_string()[0]
        print(222)
        users = UserInfoUtil.get_info(id,uid)
        print(users)
```

I wrote in UserInfoUtil like

```
class UserInfoUtil(object):
  def user(d, id, uid, Data=False):
    if Data:
      for user in id.userEs().query({'query': {'data': {'user': uid}}}):
        return UserInfoUtil.createUser(id user)
    else:
      for user in id.user().query({'id': Id(uid)}):
        return UserInfoUtil.createUserInfo(id, user)
    return None
```

I wrote get_info like

```
@classmethod
  def get_info(cls, id, uid, ignore_home_work=True, ratio_class=1, date_type="everyday"):
    results = id.get_info(date_type).query(params)
    if len(results)==0:
      return []

    for idx,place in enumerate(results):
      if data and idx < 2
        continue
      if place['rate'] <= ratio_class:
        places.append(RFLUserInfoUtil.createUserHighRatioStayPlace(id, place['uid'], place))
    return places
```

I do not think I dealed with much data in program.So I really cannot understand why this error happens.print(111)&print(222) is shown in terminal, but print(users) is not shown.I think Timeout causes this error ,so I rewrote timeout is 1000,but same error happens.Why does this error happen?How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add `UserInfoUtil.get_info()` function code as well

Comment: @anuragal I added info more.If you know something, please help me.

Comment: `results = id.get_info(date_type).query(params)` what this statement is doing? what is the value of params? I feel here you are getting error. Do some debugging on this.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a function named `get_info` in class `UserInfoUtil`. Please make sure you add that function in the class.

```
class UserInfoUtil:
    def get_info(arg1, arg2):
        <your function code here>
        ...
        ...
        return var_to_return
```

Comment: I added info more.If you know something, please help me.